# Tabulator - Is there a way to prevent header filtering and only apply header filters programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I have a table that has 15 columns with headerFilters using ajaxFiltering.

I would like to be able to type in all of my filter criteria into the header filters and then press a button to apply the filters all at once. I have tried using `headerFilterLiveFilter:false` but that only stops the live filtering while typing in that headerFilter. Once I click into another headerFilter it applies the previous filter and I have to wait to type the next criteria.

Anything I missed in the docs or any workarounds are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a `customHeaderFilter`. Then in your function you can decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply filters that the user cant change then you shouldn't be using header filters, you should be using standard filters, these can be added by calling the `setFilter` function.

```js
table.setFilter("name", "!=", "Steve");
```

This function can also accept multiple filters at once, as an array:

```js
table.setFilter([
    {field:"age", type:">", value:52}, //filter by age greater than 52
    {field:"height", type:"<", value:142}, //and by height less than 142
    {field:"name", type:"in", value:["steve", "bob", "jim"]}, //name must be steve, bob or jim
]);
```